# JSF1091: No mime type could be found

Tags: java, jsf

I'm newbie to `JSF` and when I tried to test a simple code I got this `error`.

I have a class `Person.java(ManagedBean)`:-

```
@ManagedBean
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    // Setters/Getters for firstName, lastName, age

    public String concatMyInfo(){
        return "My name is : " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ... and my age is :" + age;  
    }

}
```

and I have a file named `test.xhtml` :-

```
<h:form>
        FirstName :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.firstName}" /><br/>
        LastName :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.lastName}" /><br/>
        Age :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.age}" /><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="click me" action="#{person.concatMyInfo}" />
</h:form>
```

I got this error :- `WARNING: JSF1091: No mime type could be found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a `String` from a method called by an `UIInput` (in this case, `<h:commandButton>`), the `String` should be the name of the view to forward after processing the request.

If you just want to test if the method is being executed by JSF, then use a simple `System.out.println` instead and change the method to `void`. For example:

```
public void concatMyInfo() {
    System.out.println("My name is : " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ... and my age is :" + age);
}
```

If you want to update a value that will be shown to the user in the next view, then use a new field in your managed bean and return the name of the view. For example:

```
@ManagedBean
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
    private String resultMessage;

    // Setters/Getters for firstName, lastName, age and resultMessage

    public String concatMyInfo() {
        resultMessage = "My name is : " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ... and my age is :" + age;
        return "result";
    }
}
```

Then, create a new page `result.xhtml`:

```html
<!--
    Boilerplate code not added here. The page should contain
    <html>, <h:head>, etc. No need of a <h:form>
-->
<h:body>
    Hello! #{person.resultMessage}
</h:body>
```

If you want to show the data in the same page, then just do not return anything from your method. When having a void method, JSF will *refresh* the current view. The code should be:

```
public void concatMyInfo() {
    resultMessage = "My name is : " + firstName + " " + lastName + " ... and my age is :" + age;
}
```

Then, in your view, add the message anywhere, probably at the bottom:

```html
<h:form>
        FirstName :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.firstName}" /><br/>
        LastName :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.lastName}" /><br/>
        Age :
            <h:inputText value="#{person.age}" /><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="click me" action="#{person.concatMyInfo}" />
</h:form>
<br />
Result: Hello! #{person.resultMessage}
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the String value in the same page other than other.